# Move list attachments to document library

Tags: 2013, document-set, attachments, drop-off-library

**Scenario**

I have a workflow built that runs on a document set.  The workflow runs well, but there are some problems that we are encountering regarding having business users submit documents to this library and set.

The way it is set up right now, is that a user submits each document to a drop off library and then is required to fill out a form for each document they submit.  Once the form is filled out, the document(s) are routed to the correct library.

Once they have been routed to the correct library, the library owner creates a document set and places the corresponding documents in their sets.

**Issues**

There are two problems with this:

1. The owner of the end library needs to manually enter the metadata from the individual documents and attach them to the document set.  The workflow is running through the document set, not the documents individually.  The metadata that the submitter enters is needed but right now we don't have a better way set up for them to attach the metadata to the not-yet-created document set.
2. Because the submitter needs to provide metadata and check a box in order for the document to be routed, all documents that they submit have forms that need to be filled out.

   - If they submit a group of four documents that all belong to the same document set, it is not set up for them to only fill out a single form.  They would have to, at minimum, open the form for each document and check the box to route the document as well as fill out one of the forms with the correct document set metadata.

**Requirements/Attempted Solutions**

I have been trying to figure out an easy way for the business user to submit a group of documents as well as provide the metadata for the document set once, rather than for each document.

There are requirements that it needs to be very easy to submit the documents for the business users.  So that eliminates having them create a document set themselves, placing documents in it, and then sending it out through the drop off library.  I have been having problems setting up a document set with a drop off library anyways.

One idea that we have started to try is to create a custom list and use that as the document set form.  With that use the attachments feature.  My idea would be, when the item is saved it moves or copies the attachments to the correct library and I am left with an item that has all of my document set metadata.  I haven't had any luck in finding a way to move/copy attachments however.